# Keep a Python script running in the background (while regularly running other Python script)

Tags: python

I need to keep a Python script running all the time to make constant changes to my company's Google Adwords account. However, I still need to write and run/test other Python code for other projects. What is the easy way to keep a script continuously running that does not interfere with other Python tasks? Thanks!

Comment: You can run multiple scripts concurrently, there's no issue there.

Comment: run it as a separate script, it will remain isolated from other scripts. May be you would be interested in knowing about "cron jobs" too *(google this term to know what they are)*

Comment: Just open another Terminal. Job done.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It seems like a dumb question lol. So if I put my computer to sleep, does the script stop running? Or does it only stop running if I shut my computer down? Thanks!

Comment: @AngieDinh It's not a dumb question, no worries there. But to be honest, if you're unclear about things like that, I suggest you find an engineer to handle this project, it's probably more than a DIY task.

Answer (score 0):

[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) will isolate a local Python environment for your script. This will keep it fairly safe from any other third-party Python libraries that you might install while working on other projects.

That said, if this is an important script, then you shouldn't be running it on your local ("dev") workstation in the first place; you should be *deploying* it to a stable production environment. Stable production environments, by definition, <s>do</s> should not change without going through some explicit, predefined procedure.